# How do you find the length of an arc given arc measure?

Tags: geometry

So I have a circle with a diameter of 160,000 miles, with three points on it that form a perfect 90 degree angle. How are you supposed to find the length of an arc based on it's angle measure *M* and if needed, the diameter *d*?

Also I was interested because I have seen a few problems that require you to know how to do this and I was only able to get the arc measure from them so far. I don't know if there is a general formula for it or something but I would like to know how to do this.

Comment: I suggested including an illustration so that the angle in question is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a very simple formula for this: the length of an arc with angle measure $\theta$ and radius $r$ is
$$\theta r$$

For this formula to work, **$\theta$ must be measured in radians.**
To convert degrees to radians, multiply the angle by $\frac{\pi}{180}$.

So in your example:

- 90 degrees is $90 \cdot \frac{\pi}{180} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ radians.
- The radius is half the diameter, or $\frac{160,000}{2} = 80,000$ miles.
- Therefore, the length of the arc is
  $$
  \theta r = \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot 80,000 = 40,000 \pi.
  $$